# filtering llistview takes a long time

Tags: vb.net, listview, filter

I am using a Listview in a form that contains some 3400 rows. When I want to filter the rows by removing the once that do not contain the string I am filtering on, it takes a very long time. Shouldn't there be a quicker way to do this?

```
Private Sub FilterListView()
        Try
            Dim pos As Int32
            Dim listItem As ListViewItem
            
            For pos = ListView1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                listItem = ListView1.Items(pos)
                If Not InStr(1, ListView1.Items(pos).SubItems(1).Text.ToLower, FilterParameter.ToLower) > 0 Then
                    ListView1.Items(pos).Remove()

                End If
            Next
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate?view=net-5.0

Comment: @HansPassant I am using VB.net

Comment: The .NET documentation does not care about language.  Look at the upper-right of that page, below the "download" button.  Click ` </> ` and select vb.net

Comment: You're probably going to be far better off doing your filtering via non-visual components, then use something like the list box to display results.  What is the origin of the data displayed in your list box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`. This prevents the screen from redrawing on every removal which slows things down considerably. A minor optimization is to change the `FilterParameter` to lower case just once before the loop rather than on every iteration.

In stead of the old VB6 `InStr` use `.Contains`. You can string methods in .net combining `.ToLower` and `.Contains`. `Contains` returns `True` or `False` so it works in the `If`.

```
Private FilterParameter As String

Private Sub FilterListView()
    ListView1.BeginUpdate()
    Dim lcSearch = FilterParameter.ToLower
    For Each listItem As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        If listItem.Text.ToLower.Contains(lcSearch) Then
            listItem.Remove()
        End If
    Next
    ListView1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```